# Is there a way to mock a Class type?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

come upon a problem at my work that wanted to ask. Is it possible to mock a Class type? I was hoping to force throw a securityexception, in what I think a method called getConstructor(class[] x) would do. Sorry I'm still new to Junit and mocking. Here's a sample code:

```
@Test(expected = SecurityException.class)
    public void test005() throws Exception {
           //PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class.class);
           Class tempclass = PowerMockito.mock(Class.class);
           //Class<Runnable> mockRunnableClass = (Class<Runnable>)mock(Class.class);

           Class[] type = null;

           Object[] value = new Object[] { 'a' };
          
           //PowerMockito.whenNew(Class.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new SecurityException());

           PowerMockito.when(tempclass.getConstructor(Mockito.anyObject())).thenThrow(new SecurityException());
           
           ClassCreator x = (ClassCreator) ClassCreator.createInstance(tempclass, type, value);
    }
}
```

The commented parts are some of the efforts I did to try to mock a Class data type. ClassCreator is a class in a separate package. If you guys want to see the error that follows after running this it's this:

java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.SecurityException> but was<java.lang.IllegalAccessError>

```
   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:380)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:126)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleInvocationTargetException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:353)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:331)

   at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)

   at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)

   at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)

   at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)

   at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)

   at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34
```

I didn't post the entire error thread for readability. But the gist of it is here. Can anyone help? If you need me to provide more information please just leave a comment. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you simply constructor an instance of the type for which `getConstructor` is supposed to throw `SecurityException`? Not clear why mocking is needed here.

Comment: I'm very skeptical that PowerMock can mock the `java.lang.Class` class. But: why not install your own `SecurityManager`?

Comment: If you are testing the `ClassCreator.createInstance`  you don't really need to mock anything ...

Comment: Not testing the createinstance. There is another class with createinstance method im testing and inside there is a getconstructor call which i hope to throw a security exception.. tempclass is the one i hope to mock but cant mock Class.. the code u see above is the test class only not the targetted class to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [java.lang.class](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#L167) source:

> Private constructor. Only the Java Virtual Machine creates Class objects. This constructor is not used [...].

no one except the JVM can construct `Class` objects. And without the ability to create a `Class` object PowerMock cannot mock methods on it.

I'm not sure what you want to prove by throwing a `SecurityException`, but one way of doing it would be to install your own `SecurityManager`.

Class `Example`:

```
package x.y;

import x.z.Tester;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        SecurityManager s = new MySec();
        System.setSecurityManager(s);
        try {
            createObject();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.out.println("Catched SecurityException!");
        }
        System.setSecurityManager(null);
        createObject();
        System.out.println("Without SecurityManager no SecurityException");
    }

    private static void createObject() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<Tester> cs = Tester.class;
        cs.getConstructor().newInstance();
    }

    static class MySec extends SecurityManager {
        @Override
        public void checkPackageAccess(String pkg) {
            if (pkg.startsWith("x.z"))
                throw new SecurityException("don't load from x.x!");
        }
    }
}
```

Class `Tester`:

```
package x.z;

public class Tester {
}
```